# Webpack is not loading local images with absolute path

Tags: image, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm a webpack beginner and I'm trying to integrate webpack 4 to my website.

My images are in `/media/user/` directory, so I've `<img>` srcs
- programatically assigned by javascript - like `http://localhost:8080/media/user/image_name.jpg`

but when I load it with webpack dev server it does not find any image.

Comment: Are you using any js framework?

Comment: @MatheusSilva nope

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put these lines in webpack config:

```
devServer: {
     contentBase: 'path.join(__dirname, /media/user)'
```

Then, it should serve static files from this folder.